# JSTree - Disable automatic selection of children on load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jstree

I need to disable the automatic selection of all children at loading time. If I set a parent node  with selected parameter to true, it will select all of its children, but I want to have only the parent node selected.

```
$('#tree_groups').jstree({
        'plugins': ["wholerow", "checkbox", "types"],
        'core': {
            'data': [{
                "id": "0-14089749041",
                "text": "Sport",
                "state": {
                    "selected": true,
                },
                "children": [{
                "id": "14089749041-14089751330",
                "text": "Pallacanestro",},
                {"id": "14089749041-14089751110",
                "text": "Tennis",},
            ]},
        "types" : {
            "default" : {
                "icon" : "fa fa-group icon-state-warning icon-lg"
            },
            "file" : {
                "icon" : "fa fa-file icon-state-warning icon-lg"
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Please share you code whatever you tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer by myself, I've just set the [three_state](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=three_state&f=$.jstree.defaults.checkbox.three_state) of checkbox plugin to false.

```
$('#tree_groups').jstree({
    'plugins': ["wholerow", "checkbox", "types"],
    'core': {
        'data': [{
            "id": "0-14089749041",
            "text": "Sport",
            "state": {
                "selected": true,
            },
            "children": [{
            "id": "14089749041-14089751330",
            "text": "Pallacanestro",},
            {"id": "14089749041-14089751110",
            "text": "Tennis",},
        ]},
    "checkbox" : {
            "three_state" : false,
        },
    "types" : {
        "default" : {
            "icon" : "fa fa-group icon-state-warning icon-lg"
        },
        "file" : {
            "icon" : "fa fa-file icon-state-warning icon-lg"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Good solve. I think you can mark your own answer as accepted as it actually answers the question. I also edited your answer and added link to documentation.

Comment: On load this configuration works that is automatic selection of child when parent checbox is selected is disabled. But it also removing the feature when parent checkbook is manually selected all its children sh be selected. Otherwise user needs select each child checkbook manually. Anyway to retain that behaviour

Answer (score 0):

I have looked for article which contains proper answer on this problem.
This can be solved on easiest possible way.
On jstree instance just add an event as i showed below

```js
.on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
    if (data.event === undefined) return false;
})
```